# JQM with swipe.js fires event one additional time for each subsequent visit, I only have the 'pageshow' event and no 'click' function or whatever

Tags: jquery-mobile, swipe.js

So I'm trying to use swipe.js in congunction with jQuery mobile.

I have it setup so that the swipe.js slider thingy will start automatically on the jqm 'pageshow' event.

I'm now running into the problem that the code in the swipe function will execute one additional time when I leave the page and comeback.

This issue seems a fairly common one with jqm, and I've read many possible solutions here on SO, and elsewhere on the internets. 
However, all of these solutions that seem to work wonderfully for others involve a secondary 'click' event within the 'pageshow' event.

These solutions for example: http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-jquery-multiple-event-triggering/ seem great, but where is my 'click' function, sadly I don't have one.

I'm a little lost because I do not have a click event.
I believe the function is bound to the 'pageshow' event... and have tried many different ways to get around this.

```
$(document).off('pageshow', '#home').on('pageshow', '#home', function() {
    var home = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
    window.mySwipe = Swipe(home, { 
        auto: 5000,
        speed: 500,
        disableScroll: true,
        callback: function(index) {
             console.log(index);
         }
    });
});
```

The code above tries to implement solution #2 from the above link by unbinding from 'pageshow' with '.off' before binding it again with '.on'.
but I'm doing it wrong, and I don't understand.

I should mention that the swipe.js appears to run perfectly, but when trying to retrieve the index value in the callback into the console the above code repeats the console.log one additional time per return to the #home page.

Also, the .js code is in the header, and I am working with one index page with multiple page ID's.

Can anyone see the dot I'm failing to connect here ??

Comment: Can you initialize swipe in "pagecreate" instead of pageshow? Also can you check if window.mySwipe is null and only initialize in that case?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried on 'pagecreate' but nothing loads, I believe because the elements of the swipe are not loaded into the DOM at that point.

Comment: I've tried to 'if (window.mySwipe == null)' inside the function, the images do not load, or the swipe does not load. Perhaps I'm not doing that correctly.??